# Error in IF THEN ELSE for Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, sequence

I'm trying to create a if then else in my pl sql code but the below receives an error. I currently use the code to create an automated sequence but when I try to insert the below it results in error because O_IDis an integer in the able of Orders. How can I declare a sequence

```
 set serveroutput ON;
 DECLARE
O_ID orders.o_id%type;
Order_Date orders.order_date%type;
Shipment_Date orders.shipment_date%type;
Delivery_Date orders.delivery_date%type;
Shipping_Method orders.Shipping_Method%type;
Shipping_days shipping.shipping_days%type;
Delivery_days shipping.delivery_days%type;

Regular number := 3;
Express_shipping number := 2;

   Begin
   O_ID := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL';
   Order_Date := SYSDATE;
   Shipment_Date := SYSDATE;
Delivery_Date := SYSDATE;
   Shipping_Method := 'Regular';

Shipping_days := 3;
Delivery_days := 5;

    IF Shipping_Method = Regular THEN 
        Shipping_Days := 3;
        Delivery_days := 5;

    ELSIF Shipping_Method = Express_shipping THEN 
        Shipping_Days := 1;
        Delivery_days := 2;
    END IF;

   Insert into Orders(O_ID,Order_Date,Shipping_method,Shipment_date,Delivery_date,Shipping_method)
   Values(O_ID,Order_Date,O_ID,Order_Date,Shipping_method,Shipment_date,Delivery_date,Shipping_method);
  COMMIT;   
  dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: ' || O_ID);
END;
```

Error:

```
ERROR at line 1: 
 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error 
 ORA-06512: at line 26
```

Comment: Seems a little odd to have the if/else anyway when you assign the value 'Regular' to `Shipping_Method`; but it can not be compared to either number variable. Did you really mean the two string assignments (that and the sequence for OID) to be string literals?

Comment: I would like to be able to use the if then else statement and not have to declare the variables. If I use a string then hopefully I would not need to declare.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not declaring a string; isn;t `O_ID` suppose to be a number from the sequence, not the string literal that contains the sequence name? Where will the values you're comparing come from - Is this going to become a stored procedure and they will be passed in? Adding the definition of the orders table might be helpful too, to clarify the data types you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this procedure I will declare dif type of data such as dates, automated order ID, products, etc. the main portion of this is to calculate the total and create a unique ID. However, O_ID is an integer and will not allow me to declare O_ID as orders_seq.NEXTVAL for the sequence.

Comment: As a general comment, it really is worth getting into the habit of formatting your code consistently, as it becomes easier to take in the structure of it, and often errors jump out at you. Pick an indent size and a case convention and stick to them :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is the variables  in SHIPPING_METHOD.  If they are a string then you cannot do this comparison

```
IF Shipping_Method = Regular THEN

this should be 

IF Shipping_Method = 'Regular' THEN
```

You could declare CONSTANT VARCHAR2(20) to represent the shipping methods and this would reduce the chance of errors.

```
DECLARE
c_shipping_regular CONSTANT VARCHAR2(20) := 'Regular';

BEGIN
IF Shipping_Method = c_shipping_regular THEN
....
```

Comment: Seems that I am declaring the sequence wrong for O_ID.

Declare
O_ID int := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL';
Begin
    O_ID := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL';

OR
  
DECLARE
 O_ID orders.o_id%type;
Begin
    O_ID := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL';

Comment: There is a variable named `regular` in the code, so I think that line is actually OK.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Agreed, confusing to have a variable named regular and a fixed string 'Regular' so I would still refactor to use a constant and a naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

```
DECLARE
O_ID orders.o_id%type;
Order_Date orders.order_date%type;
Shipment_Date orders.shipment_date%type;
Delivery_Date orders.delivery_date%type;
Shipping_Method orders.Shipping_Method%type;
Shipping_days shipping.shipping_days%type;
Delivery_days shipping.delivery_days%type;

Regular number := 3;
Express_shipping number := 2;

Begin
   --O_ID := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL';
   -- Must be
   O_ID := orders_seq.NEXTVAL;
   Order_Date := SYSDATE;
   Shipment_Date := SYSDATE;
   Delivery_Date := SYSDATE;
   --Shipping_Method := 'Regular';
   -- Either use the number or define constants and use them
   Shipping_Method := 3;

   Shipping_days := 3;
   Delivery_days := 5;

    IF Shipping_Method = Regular THEN 
        Shipping_Days := 3;
        Delivery_days := 5;

    ELSIF Shipping_Method = Express_shipping THEN 
        Shipping_Days := 1;
        Delivery_days := 2;
    END IF;

   Insert into Orders(
      O_ID, 
      Order_Date,
      Shipping_method,
      Shipment_date,
      Delivery_date,
      Shipping_method)
   Values(
      O_ID,
      Order_Date,
      --O_ID,
      --Order_Date,
      Shipping_method,
      Shipment_date,
      Delivery_date,
      Shipping_method);
  COMMIT;   
  dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: ' || O_ID);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are trying to assign a non numerical value to a numerical field. Looking at your insert statement things look wrong. You put o_id, order_date twice in the values().

```
insert into orders
   (o_id
   ,order_date
   ,shipping_method
   ,shipment_date
   ,delivery_date
   ,shipping_method)
values
   (o_id
   ,order_date
   ,o_id
   ,order_date
   ,shipping_method
   ,shipment_date
   ,delivery_date
   ,shipping_method);
```

Comment: I was trying to input the fields that I declared O_ID := 'orders_seq.NEXTVAL'; My goal is to have this assign unique ID's when I runt he procedure for a new order.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set variables that should be numbers using string literals. It looks like at this point in your experimentation you're trying to set the value of your `shipping_method` variable to 3 via the `regular` variable; but because you've put it in single quotes you're assigning a string literal (`'Regular'`) not a number (`Regular` without quotes, or just `3`). You're doing the same with `O_ID`, assigning the string literal instead of the result of the sequence `nextval` call. I think you meant to do:

```
O_ID := orders_seq.NEXTVAL;
Shipping_Method := Regular;
```

But you've said in a comment that the `shipping_method` column is actually a string, so declaring the `regular` and `express_shipping` as numbers, and setting them to 2 and 3, doesn't really make sense. If they should be string values then declare and set them appropriately, using whatever values you will actually have in that column:

```
l_Regular orders.Shipping_Method%type := 'REGULAR';
l_Express_shipping orders.Shipping_Method%type := 'EXPRESS';
```

The assignment and comparison would then make more sense, though as you're using fixed values at the moment it seems redundant - presumably the `shipping_method` will be coming from somewhere else eventually.

```
DECLARE
  l_O_ID orders.o_id%type;
  l_Order_Date orders.order_date%type;
  l_Shipment_Date orders.shipment_date%type;
  l_Delivery_Date orders.delivery_date%type;
  l_Shipping_Method orders.Shipping_Method%type;
  l_Shipping_days shipping.shipping_days%type;
  l_Delivery_days shipping.delivery_days%type;

  l_Regular orders.Shipping_Method%type := 'REGULAR';
  l_Express_shipping orders.Shipping_Method%type := 'EXPRESS';

Begin
  l_O_ID := orders_seq.NEXTVAL;
  l_Order_Date := SYSDATE;
  l_Shipment_Date := SYSDATE;
  l_Delivery_Date := SYSDATE;
  l_Shipping_Method := l_Regular;

  l_Shipping_days := 3;
  l_Delivery_days := 5;

  IF l_Shipping_Method = l_Regular THEN 
    l_Shipping_Days := 3;
    l_Delivery_days := 5;
  ELSIF l_Shipping_Method = l_Express_shipping THEN 
    l_Shipping_Days := 1;
    l_Delivery_days := 2;
  END IF;

  Insert into Orders(O_ID,Order_Date,Shipping_method,Shipment_date,
     Delivery_date)
  Values(l_O_ID,l_Order_Date,l_Shipping_method,l_Shipment_date,
     l_Delivery_date);

  dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: ' || l_O_ID);
END;
```

You were also trying to insert too many values into the table as you'd repeated `O_ID`, `Order_Date` and `Shipping_method`; so I've removed the extra references.

Using column names as variable names can cause confusion and errors (particularly then updating) so I've prefixed them all with `l_` - any convention will do though. You don't really need them all; you could have the sequence and sysdate references directly in the insert instead:

```
  Insert into Orders(O_ID,Order_Date,Shipping_method,Shipment_date,
     Delivery_date)
  Values(orders_seq.NEXTVAL,SYSDATE,l_Shipping_method,SYSDATE,
     SYSDATE);

  dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: ' || orders_seq.CURRVAL);
```

Comment: The shipping_method columns is varchar but I have 2 other columns in that table that declare the days of shipment and delivery for each shipping method. Shipping days and DElivery days columns are number.

Comment: @JRock - what values will you have in the shipping_method then? And why are the values you're comparing against numbers (2 and 3)?

Comment: Alex - I re-did my table so that each shipping method now has an ID. IF S_ID = 1 THEN 
Shipping_Days := 3;
Delivery_days := 5;
Shipping_cost := 5;

ELSIF S_ID = 2 THEN 
Shipping_Days := 1;
Delivery_days := 2;
Shipping_Cost := 20;
END IF;

Comment: @JRock - those should probably be in a look-up table rather than hard-coded in the PL/SQL block; you could still get them and store them in the orders table if you wanted to preserve the values as they were when the orders were raised - in case they change in the future. Or keep a history and figure out what they were on the order date as needed.

Comment: not really sure what you mean by the above? I would use a select query to auto fill certain fields?

Comment: @JRock - that is what I meant really; you just aren't yet, in the code you posted. Going off-topic anyway *8-)

Comment: that's actually what I would like to do. I posted another post with trying to reduce the hard code in my program to use more that targeted in my begin statement.

Comment: Is there a way to declare a variable with a select statement? Below is an example.

Declare
 P_Price orders.p_price%type;
Begin 
    P_Price := (select price from products where p_id = 1000); 

Look up price in a table to declare the price

Comment: @JRock - [see the docs: `select into`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm). i.e. `select price into p_price from products where p_id = 1000;`. Seems you need to read up on the fundamentals of the language.